# Find Recording from nvr using onvif within specific time

Tags: onvif, python-onvif

we are using Dahua NVR and we stream live cameras through it. As Dahua stores the recordings in somewhere we want to access the past recordings (of specific time). The code I mentioned gives the whole saved recording of NVR. But as I said I want specific time's recording. I have provided the filter for that as well but it seems to be not working probably. Please guide.

## Link to Download the onvif 2 library

https://github.com/yingchengpa/python-onvif2-zeep/tree/master

## Code

```
from onvif2 import ONVIFCamera, ONVIFService

nvr_ip = "192.168.11.155"
nvr_username = "admin"
nvr_password = "admin123"


nvr = ONVIFCamera(nvr_ip, 80, nvr_username, nvr_password,wsdl_dir=
"/home/itsupport/Desktop/vms_1/python_onvif2_zeep_master/wsdl" )


media_service = nvr.create_media_service()
record_search = nvr.create_search_service()
replay = nvr.create_replay_service()


filter= "boolean(//Track[TrackType = 'Video']),2023-08-20T08:07:43.000Z,2023-08-22T08:07:43.000Z,1,10,1")

scope = {"Scope" : {"RecordingInformationFilter": filter },
         "KeepAliveTime":"PT60S"}

source_token = record_search.FindRecordings(scope)
get_result = record_search.GetRecordingSearchResults(source_token)
```